Second Level Factor in CFA - how to interpret standardized path coefficients
I have seen such a model in publications many times, which I created on my own data. It is a model of three latent features based on observable variables (likert scales) which also has a superior factor. There are standardized coefficients in the chart generated in AMOS.

I have a few questions to understand this model type. They are theoretical rather than practical, so I do not include the data.

First of all, there is the issue of naming: I have not found a good name for such a model, is this model professionally called "second level factor", "second order factor", or something else? Are there tutorials for such models somewhere, e.g. in R or AMOS?

Is such a model in fact a single or multidimensional model? If all the individual latent factors are essentially combined into one higher level factor, does this mean that there is really only one practical big-factor, "forcibly" divided into three by the researcher (me)? For example - factor analysis PCA/CFA would rather give a one-factor solution? Is there any literature that talks about this or settles it?

Now let's look at the standardized path values ​​from the general latent factor to the individual latent factors (general->F1, general->F2, general->F3). Can this solution standardized by coefficients compare the values ​​of individual smaller latent factors for the model? For example - can it talk about which of the sub-factors explains the superior-factor to a greater extent? Or does it account for a larger percentage of the variance in the superior-factor? Or is it more consistent with the overarching superior-factor? Also - is there any literature that would address this issue?


Thank you in advance for all your tips.

I believe the most common name is "second-order confirmatory factor analysis".


"Second-order factor model" or "hierarchical factor model" would probably be the most common terms for such a model.

It is a multidimensional factor model because there are three (uncorrelated) specific (residual) factors (e13, e14, and e15) in addition to the general factor. The model is not equivalent to a unidimensional model with a single first-order factor on which all indicators load.

The standardized second-order loadings give the bivariate correlations between the general factor and the first-order factors F1-F3. The squared standardized loadings give R^2, which is interpretable as the proportion of variance in a first-order factor that is "explained" or accounted for by the second-order (general) factor. You can use the standardized loadings to determine which first-order factor best represents or "measures" the general factor (in this case F2 with a standardized loading of .77).



Thank You. Just a question about second point (2). Do I understand correctly that the difference between a one-dimensional and a multidimensional model in the case of such model are errors (e13, e14, e15)? If I remove them from the model (path drawing) and calculations, will I get a one-dimensional model? I did this on the above data. After removing these residuals, why does AMOS for all three paths: G->F1, G->F2 and G->F3 show a standardized value of 1? How to understand this?

Yes, when you remove the residuals e13, e14, and e15, the model becomes a unidimensional model in which 100% of the variance of the first-order factors is accounted for by the general (second-order) factor. Therefore, the standardized loadings must be 1.0 in that case (the standardized loadings squared give R-squared; 1^2 = 1 [100% explained variance]).

Actually i'm lost here. I fully understand how this assumption works, but I don't understand the idea that 100% of the variance is to be explained by the second-order factor. That's impossible, especially if one second-order factor have to explain many subordinate factors. Where does this assumption come from? I mean - why do we assume this? And are there any other methods that would similarly determine the contribution of subfactors to the "parent" factor?

I think you got this backwards. The second-order factor explains variance in each first-order factor. The first-order factors do not "contribute" to the second-order factor. When you remove the residual (error) from a first-order factor, by definition, 100% of the variance of that first-order factor is accounted for by the second-order factor and the standardized loading must be 1. This is because there is no residual variance in that case. Everything is accounted for.
